# EnvironmentNotWritableError problem while installing python package in anaconda terminal

Tags: python, anaconda, package

After downloading the 'linearmodel' package of python using the instruction:

```
conda install -c conda-forge linearmodels
```

in base root condo terminal got this problem in conda prompt :

```
 Preparing transaction: done
 Verifying transaction: failed

 EnvironmentNotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to the target 
 environment.
 environment location:
```

the version of conda on windows 10 is

> 4.8.3

I'll appreciate helping me solve it.

Answer (score 0):

As it says, you don't have write permission, So maybe running the command prompt as **administrator** will work.

Comment: thanks for commenting,
but I've done this before, again have the same problem